# django contrib message appearing behind my input instead on top

Tags: python, django, message

I have a contrib message that appear when the user login information is not valid!

```
messages.info(request, "Sorry, your password was incorrect.")
```

but the problem is that the pessage pop behind my input(So we can't clearly see the message) , I want to make it appear on top on my Login input....I tried to change the code position of the `{{ message }}` on my html files but it didn't worked. Maybe the problem is on my css files? Thanks for helping....

login.html

```
{% load static  %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "test.css" %}">

<head>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the above in your HEAD tag -->
</head>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="main">


    <div class="container">
<center>
<div class="middle">
      <div id="login">

        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

          <fieldset class="clearfix">

            <p ><span class="fa fa-user"></span><input type="text" name="username" Placeholder="Username" required></p> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Username" -->
            <p><span class="fa fa-lock"></span><input type="password" name="password"  Placeholder="Password" required></p> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="Password" -->

             <div>
                                <span style="width:48%; text-align:left;  display: inline-block;"><a class="small-text" href="#">Forgot
                                password?</a></span>
                                <span style="width:50%; text-align:right;  display: inline-block;"><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></span>
                            </div>

          </fieldset>
<div class="clearfix"></div>


      </div> <!-- end login -->
      <div>
      <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/Ozr5pDW.png">
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>

      </div>
</center>
    </div>

</div>
```

test.css

```
@charset "utf-8";


@import url//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);




div.main{
    background: #0264d6; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0264d6 1%, #1c2b5a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(1%,#0264d6), color-stop(100%,#1c2b5a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0264d6 1%,#1c2b5a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0264d6 1%,#1c2b5a 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0264d6 1%,#1c2b5a 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #0264d6 1%,#1c2b5a 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0264d6', endColorstr='#1c2b5a',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
height:calc(100vh);
width:100%;
}

[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0px auto;

  &:before,
  &:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

}

body {

    color: #606468;
  font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

input {
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;

  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
  }

  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }

}

.container {
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* ---------- LOGIN ---------- */

#login form{
    width: 250px;
}
#login, .logo{
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
}
#login{
border-right:1px solid #fff;
  padding: 0px 22px;
  width: 59%;
}
.logo{
color:#fff;
font-size:50px;
  line-height: 125px;
}

#login form span.fa {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}

#login form input {
    height: 50px;
}
fieldset{
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    margin: 0;

}
#login form input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 0 16px;
    width: 200px;
}

#login form input[type="submit"] {
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* margin-bottom: 2em; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

#login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #d44179;
}

#login > p {
    text-align: center;
}

#login > p span {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.middle {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Well, it is due to placement of your tags(try placing message tags block inside login block). Basically it can be handled using html and css only. However, Django provides built in form errors which can be automatically rendered on fields, so that you don't need to render your form errors using messages. If you want I can provide some resources for doing this.

Comment: I tried it and it does the samething...